# Cannot install packages

Tags: debian, g++

I get the following whenever I try to install a package:
(g++-12 in this case)

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  binutils-common:i386 binutils-i686-linux-gnu:i386 lib32asan8 lib32atomic1 lib32gcc-12-dev lib32gcc-s1 lib32gomp1 lib32itm1 lib32quadmath0 lib32stdc++6 lib32ubsan1 libasan8:i386 libbinutils:i386
  libc6-dev:i386 libc6-dev-i386 libc6-dev-x32 libc6-i386 libc6-x32 libcc1-0:i386 libcom-err2:i386 libcrypt-dev:i386 libctf-nobfd0:i386 libctf0:i386 libgcc-12-dev:i386 libgmp10:i386 libgomp1:i386
  libgprofng0:i386 libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 libisl23:i386 libitm1:i386 libjansson4:i386 libk5crypto3:i386 libkeyutils1:i386 libkrb5-3:i386 libkrb5support0:i386 libmpc3:i386 libmpfr6:i386
  libnsl-dev:i386 libnsl2:i386 libqt5webkit5 libquadmath0:i386 libssl3:i386 libtirpc-dev:i386 libtirpc3:i386 libubsan1:i386 libx32asan8 libx32atomic1 libx32gcc-12-dev libx32gcc-s1 libx32gomp1
  libx32itm1 libx32quadmath0 libx32stdc++6 libx32ubsan1 linux-headers-6.1.0-11-common linux-kbuild-6.1 linux-libc-dev:i386 lshw qml-module-qtwebkit x11-apps x11-session-utils xinit
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  g++-12
Suggested packages:
  g++-12-multilib gcc-12-doc
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  teamviewer-monitoring
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  g++-12
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 1 to remove and 17 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/10.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 32.2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 233626 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing teamviewer-monitoring (23.6.9001) ...
rm: cannot remove '/var/opt/teamviewer-rm/*.json': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package teamviewer-monitoring (--remove):
 installed teamviewer-monitoring package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 teamviewer-monitoring
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Not sure what to do..

TIA.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us your operating system. Yes, you've tagged with Debian, but which Debian? Or which Debian based distribution? Please makes sure to always include the actual OS in the question itself. Also make sure to show us the command you ran. Is that `apt install g++`? `apt-get install g++`? Something else?

Comment: What is the situation with teamviewer? Have you removed it manually?

Answer (score 2):

The maintainer scripts provided with the `teamviewer-monitoring` package that is currently installed seem to be broken; the simplest solution to unblock things is to remove them:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/teamviewer-monitoring.*rm
```

If you want to try removing it cleanly, you could try fixing those scripts instead.

Once the scripts are removed or fixed, you’ll be able to finish removing `teamviewer-monitoring` and install other packages.

Comment: I would probably try "creating" one of the files the script is trying to remove (with a command like `touch var/opt/teamviewer-rm/a.json`) first, just in the hope that anything good that script does still gets done. But that might just lead to them failing on doing something else, removing them has a higher chance of getting rid of the blockage. Fixing the scripts is the better (but harder) solution.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you.